# Decrease size of test/dev mysql DB docker image

Tags: mysql, docker

We have a weekly CI build that produces a docker image of a sanitized, scrambled, and minimized (but still representable) production database (mysql) that we use for local development. Pulling the latest image always requires pulling a 10gb docker layer with all the `.ibd` files. We use file-per-table layout, and many of those tables do not change from week to week. Is there any sensible way to reduce the amount of data docker needs to download every time? Perhaps some layer-per-table setup? Have you dealt with similar needs in a different way altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Pull the static part of the 10g of file first, in its own Dockerfile line:

```
...
COPY static-ibd/*.ibd /var/lib/mysql/mydb/
COPY no-so-static-ibd/*.ibd /var/lib/mysql/mydb
```